# Proof of Stone's Theorem on unitary groups

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation, operator-theory, quantum-mechanics

I dont understand a particular step in the proof of Stone's Theorem [ B.C. Hall, "Quantum Theory for Mathematicians",p.210-213]. Let me state the Theorem and explain where I got stuck.

**Stone's Theorem**:

Suppose $U(\cdot)$ is a strongly continuous one-parameter unitary group on a Hilbert space $H$. Then the infinitesimal generator of $U(\cdot)$ is densely defined and self adjoint and $U(t)= e^{itA}$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

**Proof:**

After proving that $A$ is densely defined one shows that $A$ is symmetric and essentially self adjoint. Then one defines $V(t):=e^{it\bar{A}}$, where $\bar{A}$ is the closure of $A$. Now it suffices to show that for an arbitrary $\psi\in Dom(A)$ the function $w(t):= U(t)\psi-V(t)\psi=0$ for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$.


Now comes the part where I have problems. In the book it is claimed that
$$
\frac{d}{dt}w(t)=iAU(t)\psi-iAV(t)\psi
$$
Since $A$ is the infinitesimal generator of $U$ it is clear that $\frac{d}{dt}(U(t)\psi)=iAU(t)\psi$. The infinitesimal generator of $V(t)$ however is $\bar{A}$, so that $\frac{d}{dt}(V(t)\psi)=i\bar{A}V(t)\psi$. The equation above would follow if we knew that $V(t)\psi\in Dom(A)$.


It is also true that $\frac{d}{dt}(V(t)\psi)=iV(t)\bar{A}\psi=iV(t)A\psi$, so it would also suffice to show that $V(t)$ and $A$ commute.


I do not see why either of these conditions should be true. Maybe there is something else that I am missing here.

Comment: Since $U(t)\psi\in Dom(A)$ and $\bar{A}$ is an extension of $A$ we get $\frac{d}{dt}w(t)=i\bar{A}U(t)\psi-i\bar{A}V(t)\psi=i\bar{A}w(t)$. This suffices to get $\frac{d}{dt}\|w(t)\|^2=0$ and finish the proof. Since then $A$=$\bar{A}$, the equation is correct but the question, how to obtain it directly remains open